# Evo 3D constantly locking up

Tags: performance, htc-evo-3d

I have the Sprint Evo3D, and as of late its been locking up a lot. When it locks up, the screen is no longer interactive, nor the buttons at the bottom. I have to power it off and then back on then I can use it again. This happens frequently, almost every time I use it. Sometimes have to power it off 2 or 3 times in a row to use it again.

I've had a few ROM updates, and its been happening since maybe 3 updates ago? Hard to remember. I've done a factory reset and haven't reinstalled anything but its still happening.

Running Android 2.3.4, HTC Sense 3.0, Software 2.17.651.5, PRL 21083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution was a whole new phone...

Comment: My dad had an Evo as well, and it locked up all the time, so this is very likely the best answer.